# Gridgain executor service

Tags: java, executorservice, gridgain, gridify

What are the advantages of using GridGain's GridExecutorService to execute jobs remotely vs using the @Gridify annotation?

You can pass an instance of java.lang.concurrent.ExecutorService to your class and have no dependency on the grid framework but do you lose any functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I found the answer myself. Apparently failover is difficult to achieve using the ExecutorService abstraction and the standard GridTask mechanism should be used:

http://www.gridgainsystems.com/jiveforums/thread.jspa?threadID=840&tstart=-1